# pandas - total holdings for dates based on transaction quantities and dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to be able to determine the holdings at points in time based on a table of transactions, like this...

```
transaction    date         amount
initial        2018-10-12   3
additional1    2018-10-13   1
additional2    2018-10-15   5
```

The output would show holdings at each date in a selected date range...

```
date         holdings
2018-10-11   0
2018-10-12   3
2018-10-13   4
2018-10-14   4
2018-10-15   9
```

I feel this type of question must have been answered somewhere before on stackoverflow but bugger me if i can find it!

I've started by populating a dataframe index with the selected date range:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2018-10-11', end=date.today()))
```

I'm thinking the next step is to use a for loop with groupby and cumsum, but I just cannot work it out. Also worried that using a loop would be slow on large datasets.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
    In [186]: df1
    Out[186]: 
       amount        date
    0       3  2018-10-12
    1       1  2018-10-13
    2       5  2018-10-15

    In [188]: df
    Out[188]: 
            date
    0 2018-10-11
    1 2018-10-12
    2 2018-10-13
    3 2018-10-14
    4 2018-10-15
    5 2018-10-16

    In [192]: d2 = pd.merge(df,df1,on='date', how='left')

    In [193]: d2['cumulative'] = d2.amount.cumsum()
    In [195]: d2
Out[195]: 
        date  amount  cumulative
0 2018-10-11     NaN         NaN
1 2018-10-12     3.0         3.0
2 2018-10-13     1.0         4.0
3 2018-10-14     NaN         NaN
4 2018-10-15     5.0         9.0
5 2018-10-16     NaN         NaN

In [202]: d2 = d2.fillna(method='ffill')

In [203]: d2
Out[203]: 
        date  amount  cumulative
0 2018-10-11     NaN         NaN
1 2018-10-12     3.0         3.0
2 2018-10-13     1.0         4.0
3 2018-10-14     1.0         4.0
4 2018-10-15     5.0         9.0
5 2018-10-16     5.0         9.0
```

Comment: `d2.fillna(method='ffill')`